# Part of surface plot missing

Tags: pgfplots

I have created the following plot using pgfplots

[image]

I'd like to remove the white patches (marked in red). Here's my code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[grid = major, grid style={dotted},
zticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}, xlabel = $x_{1}$, ylabel
= $x_{2}$, zlabel=$\Delta F$]
        \addplot3[surf, shader = faceted, color = blue, opacity = 1, faceted color = white]
    table [col sep=comma]{Inhalt/Abbildungen/LaTeX/dat3.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I can provide the data file if necessary.

Comment: I'd try to change the viewing angle, or either decrease the line thickness or increase line spacing. The question feels _too localized_ to fit here.

Comment: They seem to be the viewers downsampling artifacts. Is it still there if you zoom in Acrobat to 6400%?